# Proving $\sum_{\text{cyc}}\, (23a-5b-c)(a-b)^2(a+b-3c)^2 \geqslant 0$

Tags: inequality, sums-of-squares, uvw, cyclic-decomposition

**Problem** ([KaiRain's problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2246130_sum_of_23a5bcab2ab3c2_gt0)).

For $a,b,c\geqslant 0.$ Prove $$\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyc}}\, (23a-5b-c)(a-b)^2(a+b-3c)^2 \geqslant 0$$

I only found a proof by $pqr.$ (Note that from *pqr's proof* we can get SOS but very ugly and my SOS solution is from that so I will not post my SOS)

Need to prove $$18{p}^{5}-136{p}^{3}q+34{p}^{2}r+288p{q}^{2}-480qr \geqslant 14\left( b-c \right)  \left( c-a \right)  \left( a-b \right) 
 ( 5{p}^{2}-16q) $$
After squaring both side$,$ it's
$$ \left( 133456\,{p}^{4}-879360\,{p}^{2}q+1585152\,{q}^{2} \right) {r}^
{2}+$$
$$+8\,p \left( 2603\,{p}^{6}-30021\,{p}^{4}q+114416\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}-
147456\,{q}^{3} \right) r+$$
$$+4\, \left( 9\,{p}^{6}-40\,{p}^{4}q-17\,{p}^{
2}{q}^{2}+196\,{q}^{3} \right)  \left(3{p}^{2} -16q \right) ^{2} \geqslant 0$$

Since $8341p^4-54960p^2q+99072q^2 \geqslant 0.$

If $133p^2-688q >0$ then $$2603\,{p}^{6}-30021\,{p}^{4}q+114416\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}-147456\,{q}^{3} \geqslant 0, 9\,{p}^{6}-40\,{p}^{4}q-17\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+196\,{q}^{3} \geqslant 0$$ then qed.

Else$,$ we have $$\Delta_r =3136\, \left( 133\,{p}^{2}-688\,q \right)  \left( {p}^{2}-3\,q
 \right) ^{2} \left( 5\,{p}^{2}-16\,q \right) ^{4}\leqslant 0.$$

Done.

But any other proof$?$

Comment: I think, it's a best way to the proof. I proved it by $uvw$, but really it's the same.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg $uvw$ and $pqr$ are same. I hope for the SOS or another solution.